# Playing a a number of different sounds using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I have a few single hit sounds(small sound effects) which I want to play when a button is pressed. Should I declare the player and then initialize the sound to the player in the IBAction of the button if I want to play different sounds on different buttons?

Or is there a method to call which you specify the sound as you play it?

the `[audioPlayer play]` statement plays what is already initialized or added to the player. How can I setup the play and call it at different places with some predefined sound?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of delay whenever you start playing a sound even if it's already loaded and all you have to do is hit [audioPlayer play]

If you need to initialize it before you play it i'd imagine the delay would be much more noticeable.

I think i'd make a separate audio player for each sound and populate an array with them. Keep an eye out for memory low messages and unload the objects if necessary but i don't think it will require much overhead.